# Android. Трансформация при скроле

Tags: android, recyclerview, transform, android-scrollview, scrollview

Как трансформироваться с одного дизайна в другой при скроле?

Например, у нас есть 2 layouts, которые работают с `RecyclerView` и мне надо понять, как трансформировать при скроле с одного вида в другой?

**1 вид:** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2 вид:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать CoordinatorLayout
Более подробно есть в статье
https://habrahabr.ru/post/270121/

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/material_flat"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:text="@string/lorem"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />
```